# How to iterate through the entities of an AutoCAD drawing?

Tags: python, win32com, autocad, dwg

I want to automate the processing of a set of AutoCAD files using Python and the COM interface. To that end I need to iterate through the entities of each drawing. So far I have been able to get the job done by using `pyautocad`.

```py
import win32com.client
from pyautocad import Autocad
import os

folder = r'C:\path\to\my\folder'
filename = 'my_file.dwg'
drawing_file = os.path.join(folder, filename)

acad32 = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
doc = acad32.Documents.Open(drawing_file)

acadpy = Autocad() 

entities = [acadpy.best_interface(obj) for obj in  acadpy.iter_objects()]
```

Is there any way to iterate through the drawing entities whithout using `pyautocad`? More specifically, I'm looking for something like this:

```py
entities = [obj for obj in  acad32.Objects]
```

Apparently `acad32` does not have any attributes similar to `Object`, `Entities` or whatever that might be useful to solve my problem:

```py
In [239]: doc.__dict__
Out[239]: 
{'_oleobj_': <PyIDispatch at 0x00000281D7C162E0 with obj at 0x00000281D79D9298>,
 '_username_': 'Open',
 '_olerepr_': <win32com.client.build.LazyDispatchItem at 0x281da18f1d0>,
 '_mapCachedItems_': {},
 '_builtMethods_': {},
 '_enum_': None,
 '_unicode_to_string_': None,
 '_lazydata_': (<PyITypeInfo at 0x00000281D7C16580 with obj at 0x00000281D7C08648>,
  <PyITypeComp at 0x00000281D7C16310 with obj at 0x00000281D7C08808>)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to iterate over the objects residing in Modelspace, you might try something along the following lines:

```
for obj in doc.Modelspace
```

If you need to iterate over all objects in all layous (not just Modelspace), you could use:

```
for lyt in doc.Layouts
    for obj in lyt.Block
```

Or, if you need to iterate over all objects in all layouts & blocks (including external references), you could use:

```
for blk in doc.Blocks
    for obj in blk
```

This is untested of course and assumes that all of these properties are exposed to the Win32 COM interface.

The official AutoCAD ActiveX reference may be found [here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-5D302758-ED3F-4062-A254-FB57BAB01C44).

Comment: How can I know which methods and properties are available? I searched the web but I didn't find relevant documentation.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to the ActiveX documentation.